# How to make images appear at the top in a react instagram clone app

Tags: reactjs, image, instagram, clone

```
import getPhotoUrl from 'get-photo-url'
import { useLiveQuery } from 'dexie-react-hooks'
import { db } from '../dexie'

const Gallery  = () => {
    const allPhotos = useLiveQuery(() => db.gallery.toArray(), [])
    
    const addPhoto = async () => {
        db.gallery.add({
            url: await getPhotoUrl('#addPhotoInput'),
        })

    }

    const removePhoto = (id) => {
        db.gallery.delete(id)
    }

    return (
        <>
            <input type="file" name="photo" id="addPhotoInput"/>
            <label htmlFor="addPhotoInput" onClick={addPhoto}>
                <i className="add-photo-button fas fa-plus-square"></i>
            </label>

            <section className='gallery'>
                {!allPhotos && <p>Loading...</p>}
                {allPhotos?.map((photo) => (
                <div className="item" key={photo.id}>
                    <img src ={photo.url} className="item-image" alt=""/>
                    <button className="delete-button" onClick= {() => {
                        const deleteConfirmed = window.confirm('Are you sure?')
                        if (deleteConfirmed) {
                    removePhoto(photo.id)}}}>Delete</button>
                </div>
                ))}
            </section>
        
        </>
    )

}

export default Gallery
```

Please I have the above code for a React Instagram app clone.  It's working fine but the images are added to the bottom or last whenever a person adds an image to the gallery.  I want to know how to make it such that the images will be added at the top.  Thanks.

Comment: The order depends on `add` and `toArray` methods of the `gallery`.

Comment: @user4980215 please can you explain further.  I've tried all I can on the methods you mentioned but it still doesn't add the picture to the top of the gallery. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice you are using `dexie-react-hooks`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort by `id` in reverse order:

```
useLiveQuery(() => db.gallery.reverse().sortBy("id"), []);
```